# VBA code to combine all worksheets into 1 worksheet except for the first worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a well-working code which combines the data for all of the worksheets in a workbook. However, I need to exclude `Workbook.Sheets(1)` from the code but despite changing the code to start from the second sheet, it is still combining *all* the worksheets. My code is pasted below.

I included an if statement that if the sheet name includes "`Week`" then carry on command but that results in that portion of the code not taking place at all.

```
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

    If LCase(sht.Name) = "Week" Then

        'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
        If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then

            Exit For
        End If

        'This above portion is the one i am referring to
```

My Code is:

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()

Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 'Range object
Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook
Set sht = wrk.Sheets(2)

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _
        "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next sht

 'We don't want screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
 'Rename the new worksheet
trg.Name = "Master"
 'Get column headers from the first worksheet
 'Column count first
Set sht = wrk.Sheets(2)
colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
     'Set font as bold
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

 'We can start loop
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
If LCase(sht.Name) = "Week" Then
     'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
        Exit For
    End If
     'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
     'Put data into the Master worksheet
    trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
End If
Next sht
 'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
trg.Columns.AutoFit

 'Screen updating should be activated
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code says 'If the worksheet name is "Week" *and* it is the last worksheet (which would be "Master") then exit For-loop'. This code wouldn't be executed, because the worksheet's name can't be "Week" and "Master" at the same time. Did you meant: If LCase(sht.Name) <> "Week" Then

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot a case sensitivity in:

```
If (LCase(sht.Name) = "Week") Then
```

That `LCase(sht.Name) = "Week"` will be always `False`, because:

```
LCase("Week") = "week" '--> True
LCase("Week") = "Week" '--> False
```

So, use:

```
If (LCase(sht.Name) = "week") Then
```

or

```
If (LCase(sht.Name) = LCase("Week")) Then
```

---

And for including or containing of "Week" use `Like` operator instead of `=` like this:

```
If (LCase(sht.Name) Like "*" & LCase("Week") & "*" ) Then
```